# Reading a file without truncating words

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a very big file that I want to read and do something. As per my code I have allocated 1024 bytes to read and then loop until everything is read. But sometimes doing so my words get truncated.

Even when I mention a size to read I want to make sure it is reading a complete word. All my words are separated by space.

```
with open('test.txt', mode='r',encoding="utf-8") as f:

          chunk_size = 1024

          f_chunk = f.read(chunk_size)

          while len(f_chunk)>0:

              for word in f_chunk.split():
                #do something  
                print (word)
              f_chunk = f.read(chunk_size)
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if there is a built-in way, but you could try something like:

```
chunk_size = 1024
data = ''
while True:
    data += f.read(chunk_size)
    if not data:
        break
    last_sp = data.rfind(' ')
    if last_sp == -1:                # No space at the end
        last_sp = len(data)
    block = data[:last_sp]
    data = data[last_sp + 1:]

    for word in block.split():
        print(word)
```

Basically, you remember the end of the last chunk for the next one - This will not work if you have word larger than your chunk size and may not if you have separator other than a single space (e.g. `'  '`).

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative approach, you could create a word generator as follows:

```
def read_word(f):
    word = []
    c = '.'

    while c:
        c = f.read(1)

        if c.isalnum():
            word.append(c)
        elif len(word):
            yield ''.join(word)
            word = []

    yield ''.join(word)

with open('input.txt') as f_input:
    for word in read_word(f_input):
        print(word)
```

This would return whole words split based on whether or not there was an alphanumeric character using `isalnum()`. So `read_word()` also removes all whitespace.

For example, if `input.txt` contained:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Hoc loco tenere se Triarius non potuit.
```

The output would be:

```
Lorem
ipsum
dolor
sit
amet
consectetur
adipiscing
elit
Hoc
loco
tenere
se
Triarius
non
potuit
```